How to Adapt Positional Encoding for 3D Patches in Vision Transformer (ViT)?
I'm adapting a Vision Transformer (ViT) model, originally designed for 2D images, to work with 3D medical images. The original ViT splits images into 2D patches and uses positional encoding to retain spatial information. In my case, I've created 3D patches from the medical images and flattened them, similar to the original 2D approach.
My question is: Since the 3D patches are flattened into 1D vectors, is it acceptable to use the original positional encoding method designed for 2D patches? Or do I need to modify the positional encoding to properly reflect the 3D spatial structure?
In my code, the positional encoding function is invoked like this:
self.pos_embed = nn.Parameter(data=get_sinusoid_encoding(n_position=num_patches, d_hid=embed_dim), requires_grad=False)

If modifications are needed, what changes should I make to effectively encode the 3D positional information?
Thanks in advance for your help!
I initially tried using the original positional encoding from the Vision Transformer directly on the flattened 3D patches, assuming it might still capture some spatial information. I expected that this approach could work, since the patches were ultimately flattened in a similar way to the 2D approach. However, I realized that simply flattening the 3D patches might lead to a loss of important depth information, which prompted me to consider modifying the positional encoding to account for 3D spatial relationships.
